# Problems running ubuntu on Asus F550C

Tags: drivers, nvidia, asus

I am fairly new to ubuntu and Linux.

I installed ubuntu on my Asus F550C,Intel i-5,nvidia geforce 720m. There are some issues installing and configuring the Graphicscard. When I install the driver (nvidia-319) my screen resolution goes down to 860x648, can't configure it otherwise.

Has anyone anny clues how to solve that?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try This And Tell Me The Results (I dont think it works for ubuntu 13.10 Try it at your own risk)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-319
```

Source: http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-nvidia-319-32-drivers-on-ubuntu-13-04-12-10-12-04-and-linux-mint-15-14-13/

Comment: Already tried that. Problem is that the resolution automatically turns to 860x648 which means my screen shows only a small sqare of teh actual size. Can't set or change it.

Comment: Try This https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution

Comment: if that fixes your issue, please tell me so i can edit my answer and put the thread as solved

Comment: That didn't do the trick unfortunately. Still the resolution is 860x640. Had to install ubuntu again to get rid of that setting. Maybe the laptop is simply incompatible.

Comment: @tarik So your resolution went back Up?? And That might be the case, You should use a different deriative if that doesent work. maybe xubuntu may do the trick, who knows!

Comment: At the moment I am running just with the Intel Graphics Chip and Nvidia not installed. It is okay for now, but it is bugging me that the graphics card is not usable.